# При сохранении товара или элемента справочника bitrix, открывается окно добавления, изменения не сохраняются

Tags: база-данных, битрикс, cms, права-доступа

Всем добрый день, соучастники.
Возникла проблема, есть проект на битриксе, есть каталог товаров и небольшое кол-во вспомогательных справочников.

При попытке редактирования "элемента меню/записи справочника" при нажатии кнопки сохранить (после внесения изменений) происходит переадресация на механизм добавления без сохранения изменений.

Пример редиректа: https://domen.ru/bitrix/admin/iblock_element_edit.php?IBLOCK_ID=4&type=catalog&lang=ru&find_section_section=17

Так же наблюдаю следующую картину при редактировании типа инфоблока:
/bitrix/admin/iblock_edit.php?type=catalog&lang=ru&admin=Y

```
[TypeError] 
Argument 1 passed to Bitrix\Iblock\Template\Helper::convertArrayToModifiers() must be of the type array, null given, called in /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/iblock/admin/iblock_edit.php on line 686 (0)
/home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/iblock/lib/template/helper.php:57
#0: Bitrix\Iblock\Template\Helper::convertArrayToModifiers(NULL)
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/iblock/admin/iblock_edit.php:686
#1: require(string)
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/admin/iblock_edit.php:1
```

Через список товары копируются и удаляются. Но именно создание и редактирование не работает.

Что пробовал:

1. Проверил настройки подключения к БД (идентичные) - менял на root - проблема сохранялась.
2. Поигрался с настройками PHP с уклоном с сторону обработки ошибок.
3. Попытался полазить в ядре - результат 0.
4. Средствами битры проверил состояние БД - все ок.
5. Сделал восстановление - все ок.
6. Накатил бекап - проблема видимо уже давно, просто не видели - поэтому проблема сохранилась.
7. Отключил вспомогательные редиректы в .htaccess - проблема на месте.
8. Уже от безысходности: вкл/выкл - кеширование.

Нужна подсказка.

Битра: 2016 год.
PHP:
PHP Version 7.1.33

Apache API Version: 20120211

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. В конфигурации PHP стояло ограничение на передачу параметров в post запросе, видимо их больше при сохранении элемента.

в etc/php.d/bitrixenv.ini
переменная max_input_vars = 50 - было.

Странно, что CMS не выдает никакой ошибки, а просто перенаправляет на создание.